# Azure Fabric stateful service reliable state error

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have deployed fabric application to azure cluster and initially everything works.But at some point i get this exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: State provider 131557496136176649 is not registered with the state manager at System.Fabric.Store.TStore`5.d__206.MoveNext()
```

This exception is thrown at RunAsync method of the service where I check if new data exists and update the reliable state collections.

Edit:
After some tests I think the problem is in that in single transaction I do changes to three IReliableDictionary objects and one IReliableQueue? Can this be the problem?

Comment: do you also create the reliable collections inside the same transaction? If so, please do that inside a separate one.

Comment: No I create them in separate transaction  before that

Comment: Post some code.