# Service fabric Exception

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-service-fabric

I have an async task that I run and the site is deployed using service fabric. I am unable to identify the issue even with the full stack I have.I have no knowledge of service fabric so any help will be appreciated.
The exception I am having is

```
One or more errors occurred. State provider 132846449321299027 is not registered with the state manager


 await ServiceFabricClient.functionname(some parameters).ConfigureAwait(false)
```

and the stack for the exception is

```
System.AggregateException:   at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Client.ServicePartitionClient`1+<InvokeWithRetryAsync>d__24`1.MoveNext (Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral) Inner exception System.InvalidOperationException handled at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Client.ServicePartitionClient`1+<InvokeWithRetryAsync>d__24`1.MoveNext:
```

Comment: No. As the product is new to me I am identifying the part where this implementation is done.

Comment: If it helps the exception is below
One or more errors occurred. State provider 132846449321 is not registered with the state manager.
Does it have anything to do with the transactions?

Comment: You can refer to [Azure Fabric stateful service reliable state error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47428129/azure-fabric-stateful-service-reliable-state-error), [Service Fabric State configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64419935/service-fabric-state-configuration) and [Get started with Reliable Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-quick-start)

Comment: Suggest you to ask a new question regarding this or edit the question with proper ask.